# What is a regular expression to check if line contains only one word?

Tags: regex

I would like to use regular express to check lines that contains only one word

Say:

```
'hello'
'hello World'
```

I tried `\w+`, but it returns 'hello world' too, any suggestions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add anchors for beginning and end of string.

Try this:
`^(\w+)$`

You can try a live demo [here](http://regexr.com/3bhpa). Notice the multiline parameter, depending on your language you either append `/m` to the regex or pass this as a parameter.

It will match lines with only one word. The other way to do this is to add "lookbehind" and "lookahead", however, this way is easier.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct. However, if someone wants to allow special characters in the word too, then  `^(\S+)$`  would work.